# Angular RouterModule.forRoot - access route path parameter, and pass it down to route data

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I need to set the data of a route in my angular module:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            [
                {
                    component: ManageProjectReleaseStageComponent,
                    path: 'ng-projects/:id/releases/:releaseId',
                    data: {
                        breadcrumb: 'View Release',
                        breadcrumbPredecessors: [
                            { label: 'Project Search', url: '/ng-projects/search' },
                            { label: 'View Project', url: '/ng-projects/:id/view' }
                        ]
                    }
                },
```

I need to get the `id` parameter out of this bit here: `path: 'ng-projects/:id/releases/:releaseId',`, and pass it into this bit here: `{ label: 'View Project', url: '/ng-projects/:id/view' }`

Because right now it is just passing the string: `":id"`.

How can I access the `:id` parameter from the `path`, to pass it into the `data`?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the router instance and fetch its params by using **[Resolvers](https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve)** instead of the router static `data`

**breadcrumb.resolver.ts**

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class BreadcrumbResolver implements Resolve<any> {   
                                                                                                
  constructor() {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
      // Get :id from the route
      const projectId = route.params.id; 

      // Initialize and Return this data
      const breadcrumb = {
          breadcrumb: 'View Release',
          breadcrumbPredecessors: [
             { label: 'Project Search', url: '/ng-projects/search' },
             { label: 'View Project', url: `/ng-projects/${projectId}/view` }     // Pass your ID value from the route
          ]
      }

      return breadcrumb;    
  }

}
```

**RouterModule**

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
     {
        component: ManageProjectReleaseStageComponent,
        path: 'ng-projects/:id/releases/:releaseId',
        resolve: {
           breadcrumb: BreadcrumbResolver
        }
        
     },
     ...
])
```

**ManageProjectReleaseStageComponent**

```
@Component({...})
export class ManageProjectReleaseStageComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
       const breadcrumb = this.route.snapshot.data.breadcrumb;    // Access your breadcrumb value
       console.log(breadcrumb);          
    }

}
```

Have created a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-resolvers?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app-routing.module.ts)** for your reference

Comment: Thanks it works great. A minor weirdness is that I am subscribing to Router.events in my BreadcrumbService, and when I use the resolver, it causes the route data to be nested in an object. I have to do this in the BreadCrumbService: `if(childRoute?.breadcrumb?.breadcrumb) {childRoute = childRoute.breadcrumb;}`. I don't think there is any way around that though, so thank you very much, great solution.

Comment: No problem, always know that the resolver can also return an observable, so you can call the breadcrumb service there and perform some logic you wish to implement. The page will only be rendered after the an observable from that resolver is done if ever you want to return an observable. Thank you very much :)